# Change default print for class object - Python

Tags: python

I have a class `Board`.

```
class Board:
    # Initialize empty n x n board
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.board = [[0]*n for x in range(n)]
        self.size_n = n
    # ...
```

I want to be able to print an object of this class with the default `print(board_obj)` function such that I get this output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I tried this but it prints the matrix in one line, which I don't want:

```
# Represent the class object as its board
def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.board)
```

Wrong output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I also do not want a custom class method like below:

```
# Custom print
def print_board(self):
    for row in self.board:
        print row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(map(repr, self.board))
```

You should use `__str__` for the human-readable version, and `__repr__` for the unambigous version.

Comment: I would avoid making `__repr__` the easy-to-read option.  There's an in depth discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), but the main point is that `__repr__` should be unambiguous, and `__str__` should be human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `__str__` method to print something nicely by default.